# To have Europocv language table in normal size

Tags: languages, europecv

Code

```
\documentclass[helvetica,narrow]{europecv}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required to draw the logo
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{europecv}
\ecvsection{Languages}
\ecvmothertongue[0.5cm]{Finnish} 
\ecvlanguageheader{(*)}
\ecvlanguage{English}{\ecvCOne}{\ecvCTwo}{\ecvBTwo}{\ecvCOne}{\ecvCTwo}
\ecvlanguage{French}{\ecvCOne}{\ecvCTwo}{\ecvBTwo}{\ecvCOne}{\ecvCTwo}
\ecvlastlanguage{German}{\ecvATwo}{\ecvATwo}{\ecvATwo}{\ecvATwo}{\ecvATwo}
\end{europecv}
\end{document}
```

I followed instructions [here](http://get-software.net/macros/latex/contrib/europecv/europecv.pdf).
I get

[image]

**How can you make the table wider?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The width of the table is limited to the document margin (as you see in the image bellow)

[image]

So you need to increase the right margin (or avoid using that table altogether). The former solution works by adding

```
\usepackage[right=3cm]{geometry}
```

[image]

Comment: After doing this change, it gives an error about the inputencoding. I had to change it to **\inputencoding{mac}** from utf-8 but this can a big problem in other operating systems. Do you have another recommendation about the inputencoding?

Comment: Your error is not because of loading geometry package. You should *not* load `inputnec` since it is already loaded by europecv document class. That is why you have conflict error when you try to load it again. Instead, you should pass `utf8` as a documenclass option, i.e., `\documentclass[utf8,helvetica,narrow]{europecv}`. See page 2 of package documentation for other options, languages and issues with babel and see section 5 for other packages that are loaded by europecv.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer in your comment! Clears up much confusion.