# What relation and dependency mistake here?

Tags: graphics, unicode, mac, europecv

Minimal case

```
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210664/13173 Do not have inputenc, since it is loaded with europecv package so defininig utf8 here
\documentclass[utf8,helvetica,narrow]{europecv}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required to draw the logo
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[right=2.5cm]{geometry} % language table impossible otherwise


% Define personal data
\ecvname{Masi} % No middle name

\begin{document}
Lorem.
\end{document}
```

I get a complaint about package problem. 
I got this kind of error last time when I had problem with a package that contained the other package which I tried to include:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/europecv/europecv.cls
Document Class: europecv 2006/04/24 (beta+Unicode TeX detection) European curri
culum vitae class
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/longtable.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/europecv/ecven.def)
./cv_masi_2.tex:3: Undefined control sequence.
\europecv.cls-h@@k ...pecv class.}}\inputencoding 
                                                  {utf8x}\let \@unprocessedo...
l.3 \usepackage
               {graphicx} % Required to draw the logo

./cv_masi_2.tex:3: LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.3 \usepackage
```

I just updated my packages by `tlmgr update --all --self` but the problem remains. 
I am in OSX Yosemite which may be cause the problem, since I have not changed by anything in the code since last time. Possible changes in packages of MacTeX may also cause the problem.

**Do you see any dependency problems in the minimal case?**

Comment: `\inputencoding` is an `inputenc` package command

Comment: Compiles jut fine on my TL14 system on LInux.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle europecv loads `inputenc`, interestingly enough, it loats it with `utf8x` no matter which class option you use.

Comment: @daleif masi neglected to mention he is using xetex or luatex

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, that was also one of my ideas, was about to ask for the complete log.

Comment: @daleif Yes. You are right! It would be very useful if these packages would be pdflatex independent and made for xelatex as a standard choice.

Comment: The implementation of a simple switch is fairly easy, please make a feature request containing a link to this question.

Comment: I mailed the maintainer who seem to be David according to Ctan. Is there some ticket system somewhere to make feature requests, other than mail?

Comment: You could always ping @DavidCarlisle here ;).

Comment: @cfr The ctan listing is essentially in error I'll ping them again to fix it, I have never used the class and don't have any access to any sources other than what's on ctan. I made a one line change to fix a bug that showed up with the 2014 inputenc release and located the original author to get permission to apply that patch. that doesn't mean I'm prepared to accept feature requests (or even bug reports:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ;).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Presumably (you did not say) you are using `lualatex` or `xelatex`. These engines do not work with `inputenc` methods. The class seems to make assumptions about use of `inputenc` so it is only written for `latex` or `pdflatex`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This solves the problem! It was for the wrong engine.