# How to get the latest euroPass in LaTeX Europecv?

Tags: europecv

The documentclass `europecv` is outdated and does not contain the latest *[euroPass](http://europass.cedefop.europa.eu/documents/curriculum-vitae/examples)*, [here](http://europass.cedefop.europa.eu/sites/default/files/cv-example-1-en-gb.pdf) an example in english. 
The latest update of the package is from 2014 [here](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/europecv?lang=en) so an alternative solution must exist.
Instructions are [here](http://europass.cedefop.europa.eu/documents/curriculum-vitae/templates-instructions) about the format. 
I sent a kind request to the author to update the package as an encrypted and signed email as the author wants. 
My old tex which output in Fig. 1, while expected output in Fig. 2

```
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210664/13173 Do not have inputenc, since it is loaded with europecv package so defininig utf8 here
\documentclass[utf8,helvetica,narrow]{europecv}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required to draw the logo

\begin{document}
\begin{europecv}
\ecvsection{Languages}
\ecvitem{English}{full working proficiency}
\ecvitem{German}{intermediate proficiency}
\end{europecv}
\end{document}
```

Fig. 1 Output of outdated Europecv package, 
Fig. 2 Expected output in *euroPass*

[image]
[image]

OS: Debian 8.7

Comment: I would kindly ask the package/class maintainer if an update in the near future could be done.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have a look at the package [europasscv](http://ctan.org/pkg/europasscv). It is actively maintained.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you! - - Output is perfect with my old Europecv code.

Comment: Now, in 2024, this package is not up to date with the latest formatting requirements established in 2020.