# How to use hyperref pdftitle in europasscv?

Tags: hyperref, cv, europasscv

I want to have pdftitle marking frontend window label correctly. 
Code

```
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210664/13173 Do not have inputenc, since it is loaded with europecv/... package so defininig utf8 here
\documentclass[english,a4paper]{europasscv}
\usepackage[british,UKenglish,USenglish,english,american]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required to draw the logo

% TODO buggy here
\usepackage[pdftitle={Leo - europass},pdfauthor={Leo}]{hyperref} % PDF setup - set your name and the title of the document to be incorporated into the final PDF file meta-information

\ecvname{Leo} 
\ecvaddress{New York, USA}
\ecvnationality{American}
\ecvdateofbirth{January 1, 1911}
\ecvbeforepicture{\raggedright}
\ecvemail{test@gmail.com}
\ecvgender{Male}
\ecvmobile{+358 12345 6789}

\begin{document}
\begin{europasscv}
\ecvpersonalinfo
\end{europasscv}
\end{document}
```

Output

```
Package Babel Warning: The package option `english' should not be used
(Babel)                with a more specific one (like `american') on input line
 5.


! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
```

Output without `\usepackage[pdftitle={Leo - europass},pdfauthor={Leo}]{hyperref}` in Fig. 1.

Fig. 1 Output without `pdftitle`

[image]

OS: Debian 8.7
TeXLive: 2017

Comment: Your question is  a bit confusing as you mention a problem with hyperref, yet you show a error related to babel. the hyperref issue, from what I can guess it that hyperref is already loaded by the class so you should have a warning about option clash somewhere in your log. Putting your `pdftitle` and `pdfauthor` in a `\hypersetup{}` instead should solve that particular problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution based on ArTourter's comment. Remove the line `\usepackage[pdftitle ... ]{hyperref}` line and add the following because `hyperref` package already loaded by `europasscv`

```
\hypersetup{pdftitle={Leo - europass}, pdfauthor={Leo}}
```

Output: correct as expected.